# How can i add $5 extra fee on choosing of UPS shipping if order is greater then $200 using shipping rules in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, shipping, shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to add shipping rule for ups shipping to add extra $5 if order total is greater then $200.

I want to use shipping Rules only as i will set many rules for different conditions.